# How to change sender of SSIS job failure emails?

Tags: ssis

The DBA who set up our SSIS jobs is no longer with the company.  However, when an SSIS job fails, it sends an email with the old DBA as the sender.

Where is this configured and how do I change it?

Comment: "It" sends an email. What is "it"? It could be your scheduling tool (SQL Agent) has an on failure job step associated with it and it's using something like sp_send_dbmail. The SSIS package itself might have an OnError event or path defined that then sends mail using a stored procedure or it connects to a mail system like Exchange. There could be a Script Task and they send email via that - the possibilities are too many to cover here.

Comment: If packages are run via SQL Agent, script that and see if there is a reference to sp_send_dbmail. If not, you'll need to dig through the SSIS package. Screenshots can help people get a high level appreciation for what the package does but the devil with SSIS is that every object on the canvas might have a "hidden" event associated to it.

Comment: @billinkc : I guess he's referring to the following: right click `job` -> `properties` -> `Notifications` -> `E-Mail`. OP Please correct if I'm not following.

Comment: @billinkc that is correct.  On the Notifications page of the agent job, email is configured to be sent to me when the job fails.  But nowhere does it say who is the sender of the email.  Would it be the email address of the AD account that owns the job?

Comment: I believe you're after the database mail configuration.    In SSMS look for "Management", expand and look for "Database Mail", right click and choose "Configure Database Mail".  That opens the wizard.   Since this is an existing setup, choose the "Manage Database Mail accounts and Profiles", next and then "View, Change..." .    That should get you going in the right direction.